# MS Access Mapping Multiple Fields From One Table to Multiple Fields In Another Table

Tags: ms-access, rdbms

In my Access database I have a parent table called **Unit** that has two fields called **unitNumber** and **floor**. In a child table called **Lease** I used the Lookup Wizard to create a foreign key called **unitIDFK** linked back to the **Unit** table and included the two fields **unitNumber** and **floor** from the **Unit** table. I need help with issues:

1. When I go to Datasheet View and add data to the **Lease** table fields, the foreign key **unitIDFK** has a drop down selection box (list box or combo box?) that displays two columns of data which are the **unitNumber** and **floor** fields from the **Unit** table. The data in both columns are selectable as one row of data, yet only the value in the **unitNumber** in the first column is populated into the foreign key field. How do I get the value in the **floor** in the second column to also populate into a field in the **Lease** table?
2. Same problem when I make the **Lease** table into a data entry form. I assume that fixing the first problem will also solve the problem of getting both the **unitNumber** and **floor** to display in the form.

I have spent the better part of today googling my question and watching lots of videos on creating relationships and editing properties in the Design View as well as searching through the archives here at Stack Overflow without any luck. Help please.

Thanks and Regards[Unit and Lease Tables Relationship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vjhdr.png)

Comment: Need code (macro or VBA) in some event (such as combobox AfterUpdate) to save the floor value. Unit numbers can be used on multiple floors? So unit and floor comprise a unique identifier? Either use autonumber as primary key in Unit table and save it as FK in Lease or create a compound key based on both unitNumber and floor and sett a relationship link on the two sets of fields. I prefer to avoid compound key.

Comment: A compound key will not help with combobox to save both fields. A combobox can save directly to only one field. Saving to another field requires code. Compound key would be used in a form/subform arrangement. Alternatively, use two comboboxes. Explore topic of cascading comboboxes.

Comment: you have a clear case of beginner confusion.  In short you need to properly separate the data (tables) and the view (form)  My answer will attempt to be a pithy walk through.

Answer (score 0):

in relational databases like access the data need to be organized as a set of normalized tables.  with a few assumptions and ignoring some columns this is what your table structure needs to look like:
[image]
[image]

Note the emphasis on letting access provide a primary key.  To make it simple the primary key is a number the database designer should never touch and the end user should never see.  Even if buildingID, floor, and UnitID form a natural 3 part key use a separate access key as your database will be busted if some manager says eek we can't have a unit 13.
Note the data for a lease is in 3 separate tables in this simple example.  Even the database designer doesn't want to tab between tables to enter each lease manually.  The end user will kindly refuse.  Instead provide a user friendly interface.  The user interface is called a form.  In particular we need a form designed for data entry as opposed to search.
Please follow along by creating the tables above and adding the 1 to many relationships using the relationships tool.  If you create the relationships first access will know how to do a better job when we create the data entry forms.
Next select the lease table under tables and click create then form on the ribbon.  Do the same for the unit table and the building table in that order.  Access will make you a nice set of starter data entry forms.
[image]

Unit Form:

[image]

I left the primary key on the lease form to show it, but I deleted it on the unit form.  the person doing data entry never has to see the tables let alone the primary keys.  Note how because we already established the relationships between tables access automatically included the lease form as a subform on the unit form (boo and yah).
What happens next depends on your actual project and end user.  For instance I used the building form to add a couple buildings cleveryly named building 1 -4.  then I right clicked on the building foreign key textbox on the unit form and selected change to combo box.  (replacing the foreign key with a user friendly name).  You can look combo boxes up but in short I left the data source as unitTable.BuildingIDFK and set the rowsource to buildings.accessprovidedID, buildings.buildingname with column widths 0,1.
Anyway default access forms are not what I would call super intuitive.  So practice and you will understand much better.  Delete the id columns.  Enter some data in the various forms and see what happens in the corresponding tables.  Delete the table data, find the form record selectors.  After seeing how the forms work and how they could be more user friendly you will have a much better idea of how to proceed.

Comment: After my original post, I did more pithy hours of pithy research and found, as you so pithfully laid out, don't setup tables intending to perform day-to-day data entry in them, just set the PKs and FKs and relationships correctly, then use forms. Your greater experienced pithy comments confirmed my lesser pithy beginner's research, and you also provided additional pithy information to get me through my next steps, including using Queries to view the database. I want to give you a reputation point but I am new with less than 15 reputation points. What a pithy. Much thanks mazoula!